# How to proceed to make Marketing Cloud API calls using JWT

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am new to the Marketing Cloud and I am trying to build an AppExchange product for my organization, for which I am using SSO through which I get a JWT and then I decode it using secret key given in the package that I have created.

I have a few questions regarding the same:

1. How do I use JWT to access user org?
2. How to do I get refresh token, Client ID/Client key that I would be needing to make the API calls.
3. Do I use the same Client Key and Client ID generated in my package to get the data from the org that the application is installed on?.

Below is my JSON response decoding the JWT.

```
{
    exp: 1542979788,
    jti: 'BNHfdmzYBMPRQRNjAaT_D8jFk_4',
    request: {
        claimsVersion: 2,
        user: {
            id: *****,
            email: '**************',
            culture: 'en-US',
            timezone: [Object]
        },
        organization: {
            id: *********,
            enterpriseId: *********,
            dataContext: '********',
            stackKey: '******',
            region: '****'
        },
        application: {
            id: '*****************',
            package: '******************',
            redirectUrl: '*****************',
            features: {},
            userPermissions: []
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Did you go through this help page? If I understand your problem, this can answer to many of your questions.

Comment: How do I get the access token without using the client ID and client Secret key? I am using marketing cloud SSO